# "Invalid expression, assumed zero" error on if-statement

Tags: pawn, sa-mp

I'm getting the following error whenever I compile my code: `"Error 029: Invalid expression, assumed zero"`

The error is thrown on the following line:

```
if ((PlayerInfo[playerid][ADMINLevel])) || (IsPlayerAdmin(playerid))
```

I want the if-statement to check if "ADMINLevel" is above zero or if the player is logged in as an RCON admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constructing your if-statement wrong. The correct way to do it is

```
if(PlayerInfo[playerid][ADMINLevel] > 0 || IsPlayerAdmin(playerid))
{
    /* Put your desired script here */
}
```

Your code was nearly correct (although it did have some unnecessary brackets), you just need to actually add a comparison to the ADMINLevel check. An if-statement should be like a question ("is admin level more than 0", rather than just "is admin level"). You can find more information about if-statements in Pawn [here](http://wiki.amxmodx.org/Pawn_Tutorial#If_Statements), and I think it will be useful for you to read.

Answer (score 1):

PlayerInfo[..][..] does not return a boolean. Add > 0 to fix it

Comment: There is no boolean type in Pawn. `bool:` is a soft tag, and any non-zero value is considered true.